# What to use as delimiter for stream of buffers

Tags: c++, serialization, flatbuffers

I'm using flatbuffers to publish stream of objects in real time. One problem I met is how to separate between independent object/buffers. If I use some characters, like `'\01'` or `'|'` then there is no guarantee that those characters would not appear in the serialised buffer. What is the recommended way to do this?

```
while (more object) {
    flatbuffers::Offset<Msg> m = foo::CreateMessage(...);
    socket.send('|');
    socket.send(fbb.GetBufferPointer(), fbb.GetSize());
    socket.send('|');
}
```

Comment: Can't you send size of the buffer at the beginning (say 4 bytes at the beginning) and then send the contents? This is usually how packet headers work right? Then you'd have no need for delimiters.

Comment: Then there is no way to get the beginning of a buffer, suppose we are in the middle of a buffer.

Comment: Is your content "streaming"? Do you know the size of the content you are going to send before you start transfer? Even if otherwise, you can use the same method. The receiver has to implement logic to read the first 4 bytes (for example) as the length of the following content.

Comment: What if the client started in the middle of buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "length prefixed buffer" (see `FlatBufferBuilder::FinishSizePrefixed` and `GetRootSizePrefixed`) both on the sending and receiving end.

You are trying to use text base delimiting and parsing methods with a binary buffer. That will never work. You need to make sure your protocol is entirely in binary.

Comment: What if the client started in the middle of buffer? is there a way to discard an imcomplete buffer?

Comment: This won't work because there is no guarantee that you received buffer from network starts with the bounbdary.

Comment: You can't start reading data in the middle.. that won't work with binary data like FlatBuffers, or even text data like JSON. You need to make sure your transport method can receive bytes sequentially from the start. Pretty much any system allows this. If you receive multiple parts over a network protocol, you need to first concatenate them until you've read a full object. If a new client connects, it needs to start receiving data starting from the start of an object.

Comment: The problem of this is it will err all messages even if just one message is corrupted or garbled, that's why we need a way to discard bad message and start fresh from there.

Comment: The other problem is even if you receive from start, you could receive half of a message in which case size prefixed would not help.